# How to rationalize an imaginary radical of the denominator?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was solving a problem, and I found this:

$$\frac{3}{i}(2 - i)=\frac{6}{i} - 3$$

According to symbolab, I must multiply by the conjugate of the denominator, then the result is:

$$=\frac{6\cdot (-i)}{i \cdot (-i)} -3= -6i - 3$$

Should a complex number always be multiplied by its conjugate?
Because if I had multiplied only by the positive $i$, the result would have been $6i - 3$, which is different.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $6 \over i$ not $6i \over i$?

Comment: You have an error.  $\dfrac{i}{i}=\dfrac{i*-i}{i*-i}=1$.

Comment: Edited Andrew Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result would NOT have been different, it would have still been $-6i-3$.

If you are multiplying by $+i$, then:

$\dfrac 3i(2-i)=\dfrac{3(2-i)}i=\dfrac{6-3i}i=\dfrac{6-3i}i\cdot\dfrac ii=\dfrac{i(6-3i)}{-1}=-(6i-3i^2)=-(6i+3)=-6i-3$

Note: If there is addition or subtraction in the denominator, meaning if complex numbers in the form $a+bi$ where $a,b\ne0$ are in the denominator, you have to multiply by the conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

If you had multiplied both numerator and denominator by $i$, it would give you the same result in this case:

$$ \frac{6}{i} - 3 = \frac{6\cdot i}{i \cdot i} - 3 = \frac{6i}{-1} - 3 = -6i - 3 $$

But when you try to rationalize a complex denominator that has both a real and imaginary part, then you *have* to multiply by its conjugate in order to make the denominator real, e.g.:

$$ \frac{6}{3 - 2i} - 3 = \frac{6(3+2i)}{(3-2i)(3+2i)} - 3 = \frac{18+12i}{13} - 3 = \frac{18 + 12i - 3\cdot 13}{13} = \frac{-21 + 12i}{3}$$

Comment: Do not forget to mention the real and complex parts are not equal to $0$.